# Macro to copy from one workbook to another - Not working

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

Good day
I am trying to run a very simple code, where I open a workbook, copy column "a:a", open another workbook and paste it there. The issue i am facing is that the data is being copied from the second workbook into the second workbook, nothing is being copied from the first.
Code below for more clarity

```
Sub Copytocurrent()

strSecondFile = "Z:\AR\AR PROGRESS\2014\MENACA REPORTS\0MENACA Working File\AR Working File\UAE\RECEIVABLE.xls"
strThirdFile = "Z:\AR\AR PROGRESS\2014\MENACA REPORTS\0MENACA Working File\AR Working File\UAE\Working File - UAE.xlsx"


Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)
Set wbk3 = Workbooks.Open(strThirdFile)

'-------------------------------------------------------'
'Copy column A in Receivable to Column XB in Working File'
'-------------------------------------------------------'

Application.CutCopyMode = False

wbk2.Sheets("receivable").Activate
With wbk2.Sheets("receivable")
Range("a:a").Copy
End With

wbk3.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
With wbk3.Sheets("sheet1")
Range("XB1").PasteSpecial
End With

'-------------------------------------------------------'
'Copy column B in Receivable to Column XA in Working File'
'-------------------------------------------------------'

Application.CutCopyMode = False

wbk2.Sheets("receivable").Activate
With wbk2.Sheets("receivable")
Range("b:b").Copy
End With

wbk3.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
With wbk3.Sheets("sheet1")
Range("XA1").PasteSpecial
End With

wbk2.Close True
wbk3.Close True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Hi. It was copying data from the same sheet "wbk3". I fixed the issue. Updated code in main question. Thanks smagnan for the reply though :). I simply added "activate" command and it worked

Comment: You're welcome, I didn't helped much (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already identified, you're issue was that you're using the activeworkbook for the copying, but forget to use `.Activate`. Better than using ActiveWorkbook, try accessing the ranges directly. This makes the code more robust - and less bloated:

```
Sub CopyToCurrent()

    Dim wbkSource As Workbook, wbkTarget As Workbook 'Alays Dim your variables to prevent errors from typos!
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Prevent screen flickering

    Set wbkSource = Workbooks.Open("Z:\AR\AR PROGRESS\2014\MENACA REPORTS\0MENACA Working File\AR Working File\UAE\RECEIVABLE.xls")
    Set wbkTarget = Workbooks.Open("Z:\AR\AR PROGRESS\2014\MENACA REPORTS\0MENACA Working File\AR Working File\UAE\Working File - UAE.xlsx")

    Set wsSource = wbkSource.Sheets("receivable")
    Set wsTarget = wbkTarget.Sheets("Sheet1")

    wsSource.Range("A:A").Copy
    wsTarget.Range("XB1").PasteSpecial

    wsSource.Range("B:B").Copy
    wsTarget.Range("XA1").PasteSpecial

    wbkSource.Close False 'No need to save any changes
    wbkTarget.Close True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note that I also added some small improvements (Dimming, prevent screenflickering)

Comment: There was a small error in your code, changed it:                    Set wsSource = wbk2.Sheets("receivable")
Set wsTarget = wbk3.Sheets("Sheet1")

Answer (score 1):

Try this, activate Workbook objects accordingly like you would do in a real copypaste flow. I run this method in a third xlsm workbook.

```
Public Sub testCopy()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\projects\excel\book1.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\projects\excel\book2.xlsx")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wb1.Activate
    With wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Range("A:A").Copy
    End With

    wb2.Activate
    With wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Range("E1").PasteSpecial
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wb1.Activate
    With wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Range("B:B").Copy
    End With

    wb2.Activate
    With wb2.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Range("F1").PasteSpecial
    End With

    wb1.Close True
    wb2.Close True
End Sub
```

edit: ok I was late you discovered the same fix by yourself a second before my post.

Comment: :) No worries, i do appreciate the time you took to answer this question, it will definitely help others facing a similar issue